# How to filter the list in blackberry cascade

Tags: blackberry-10

I need filter the list .So i store data in model and display in qml file of blackberry cascade. But now i want to filter that list. Can you please provide me simple example so that i can solve my problem.

I need some simple example for beginner .

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to set up a proxy model, getting data from your actual model, and giving your view only a subset of this data. Here is a sample filtering a model depending on the value of a TextField: https://github.com/jamespaulmuir/CascadesTextFilterableListViewSample

Answer (score 0):

What do mean by filter? If you don't want all items to appear in the list, you could try filtering the model before handing it over to the list view.